# What datatype should I used for my Date columns in SQLite with values like "2015-11-09" and "Nov-15"?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am analysing some  data from an SQLite database where I need to count the collect the change in data per month. I was wondering the most appropriate datatype to store data values like this "2015-11-09" and on a different column like this "Nov-12". These values need to be collected and compared.

I need to later on use python to create a graph with the amount of values per month.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data type (column type affinity), due to SQLite's flexibility is not really important [see](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Rather what would be important/useful/convenient is the format of the date.

As far as SQLite is concerned 2015-11-09 is the better format of the two, as the [Date and Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) cab be used directly, say to select a range, or to extract data in another format using the **strftime** function.

For example consider the following SQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (col1 TEXT, col2 BLOB, col3 REAL, col4 INTEGER, col5 a_weird_type);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
    ('2015-11-09','2015-11-09','2015-11-09','2015-11-09','2015-11-09'),
    ('NOV 9 2015','NOV 9 2015','NOV 9 2015','NOV 9 2015','NOV 9 2015'),
    ('NOV 09 2015','NOV 09 2015','NOV 09 2015','NOV 09 2015','NOV 09 2015'),
    ('NOV 19 2015','NOV 19 2015','NOV 19 2015','NOV 19 2015','NOV 19 2015')
;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date(col1) BETWEEN date('2014-01-01') AND date('2016-12-31');
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN substr(col1,4,1) = ' ' AND substr(col1,6,1) = ' ' AND substr(col1,1,3) = 'NOV' THEN
            substr(col1,7,4)||'-11-0'||substr(col1,5,1)
        WHEN substr(col1,4,1) = ' ' AND substr(col1,7,1) = ' ' AND substr(col1,1,3) = 'NOV' THEN
            substr(col1,8,4)||'-11-'||substr(col1,5,2)
        ELSE col1
    END AS colx
    FROM mytable
WHERE date(colx) BETWEEN date('2014-01-01') AND date('2016-12-31')
;
```

As can be seen from the first SELECT query and the inserted data any column type can be used. The result of the query being :-

[image]

However, then consider the 2nd SELECT query, this would only return the single row where the date has been stored as YYYY-MM-DD as **NOV** will not equate to being between **2014 and 2016** i.e. the result is :-

[image]

Rather, to select all the rows (all should be in that date range) then you'd have to use something like the third SELECT query. It being overly complex (noting this JUST copes for NOV so that's another 22 WHEN clauses to be coded for all months). This results in :-

[image]